# Does Ruby Rhod fall under rainbow umbrella, is it even established in the film?

Tags: character, the-fifth-element

When I first watched *The Fifth Element*, Ruby Rhod appeared like a [LGBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT) character to me and to show [Androgyny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgyny) signs. Does the film ever establish where he falls under the rainbow umbrella or did the makers ever address it outside the film?

<sub>Note: Even Prince, who also had rumored male relationships, was originally supposed to play that character.</sub>

Comment: What do you mean with "fall under the rainbow umbrella"? Why is this important to the plot?

Comment: @Luciano, he is asking about the ambiguous sexuality of the character, who we can ascertain is certainly Bi at least. The question seems to ask whether the tabboo of sexuality has been lifted in the future Besson's film...

Comment: @Luciano not to the plot but for understanding the character motivation towards his actions.

Answer (score 13):

There is some evidence, camp personality aside, to suggest that Ruby Rhod is bisexual; when he is 'in congress' with the female flight attendant, he exclaims;

> "This is the most fun I've ever had... with a woman!"

I'd say that's pretty definitive.

Comment: That's the only evidence in the whole movie... I'm not sure it's conclusive.

Comment: I always thought that when he said this he was talking about aliens, not men...

Comment: Or with himself.

Comment: The line is "I never felt this way before, with a human!" https://youtu.be/UENRVfdnGxs?t=148 (In [a early screenplay draft](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Fifth-Element,-The.html), it was "I've never been this sincere with a human before!")

Answer (score 5):

On [tvtropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/TheFifthElement) he is listed as an example of [Camp Straight](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CampStraight):

> A Camp Straight is a man who exhibits some or all of the common characteristics of a Camp Gay but is clearly heterosexual. He either has a girlfriend or only shows sexual attraction towards women despite his flamboyance.

In the movie he [has sex with a Stewardess](http://fifth-element.wikia.com/wiki/Stewardess) during the flight to Fholston Paradise, so he's clearly attracted to women.

Comment: But is it *only* to women?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 does he show attraction towards men? I can't remember seeing any evidence in the movie besides the sentence said in the answer by John Smith Optional.

Comment: Besides Ruby Rhod, there was also Baby Ray, that celebrity who is deaf and is surrounded by women, and one can say he is camp too. It's just speculation, but maybe in this setting what we would call camp is attractive to women?